# Change Listview countbubble programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

If you have a listview in JQuery Mobile with countbubbles defined like this:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="index.html">Inbox <span class="ui-li-count">12</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Outbox <span class="ui-li-count">0</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Drafts <span class="ui-li-count">4</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Sent <span class="ui-li-count">328</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Trash <span class="ui-li-count">62</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Is it possible to change the value of the count bubble count programmatically? Can you for example add an id to the link/a href, and change it with

```
$('#exampleID').text('12');
```

?

Comment: yes possible . u can paste u r html and jquery code in http://jsfiddle.net/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will. Here is a simple example that updates the inbox count after 5 seconds. http://jsfiddle.net/codaniel/h3vuv/1/